# Java: многопоточный сервер

Tags: многопоточность, java, сервер

Рационально ли, если на сервере для каждого соединения будет по два потока: один для приема, а другой для отправки?

Comment: гениальный вопрос... Рациональнее будет спросить правильно.

Comment: Зачем два потока? По одному на каждое соединение хватит. Код выполняется быстрее, чем пересылаются данные.

Comment: @alex91, Вы бы чуть подробней написали, что за сервер, какой в принципе протокол, требования к обработке и т.п. Я понимаю, что это у Вас в голоове, но мы-то про это **ничего** не знаем.

А на такой общий, как сейчас, вопрос Вы будете получать такие же ответы.

Comment: Архитектура такая:
Есть главный поток.Есть поток, который ждет подключение и при подключении создает поток на новое подключение.  

Для начала хочется сделать обмен сообщениями между пользователями.
Это мое первое серверное приложение и у меня есть много в голове разных идей, как это можно сделать:)  

Отправлять сообщения планирую так: будет класс, в котором будут все подключения, класс будет сделан как singleton. В каждом потоке подключении есть ф-ия SetMess, которая кладет строку в одно из полей и флаг ставит true. Поток подключения в цикле while смотрит,если тот флаг true то отправляем

Comment: Обмен сообщениями. Отложенная доставка есть или как в чате, только тем, кто онлайн?

Comment: Планируется спец программа.
Использую стандартные сокеты, тогда по идее это TCP
Доставка только тем, кто онлайн.

P.S Если честно в голове даже не допускал возможность подключения веб приложений к стандартным сокетам:)

Comment: @alex91, в Вашем случае я бы вообще сделал один поток отправки по всем сокетам. 

Т.е. для каждого соединения делаем поток, который читает. Прочитанное сообщение "роутится" на несколько участников. Так? 

Это может делать тот же поток. Затем он вместе со списком сокетов (куда отправлять) ставит это сообщение в очередь потоку отправки (одному на всех). Тот берет сообщения из очереди и перекидывает их в сокеты. Обычно задержек на send() не бывает, ОС буферизует.

Или у Вас какой-то протокол с подтверждениями?

Comment: Подтверждений пока не планируется. Очень понравилось Ваше предложение по потокам, один на всех для отправки и для каждого на чтение:) Я думаю, что так и сделаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Темную сторону силы вижу в тебе я"(c)
Вообще многопоточность нужно юзать, когда действия должны выполняться параллельно(с)Кэп.
Т.е. если Вы хотите, как я понял из комментариев, написать чат, то не рационально, если это можно так назвать. Получается один юзверь - 2 потока, как-то дофига
1 - у Вас не идет такого дикого потока информации, ради которого, нужно бы было выделять отдельный поток
2 - Количество возможных потоков не безразмерно ;-)
3 - Синхроницация, это все нужно как-то синхронизировать, пусть не сложно, но есть тонкие моменты

Лично мой совет, используйте неблокирующие сокеты и событийную модель - просто, красиво, вычурно, а потоки это если в параллель Вам декодировать, что-то нужно, сумму контрольную посчитать и пр.

Comment: Начал читать про неблокирующие сокеты. Как минимум спасибо за новую пищу для мозга:)

Answer (score 1):

Рационально только в том случае, если ваш сервер данные передает быстрее, чем выполняет код вашего приложения. Что мне кажется (бредом) фантастикой.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, надо 3: один для приема, один для отправки, и один для вычислений. Впрочем, для вычислений можно взять потоков и побольше.

Comment: Чего мелочиться, давай сразу по 10 потоков для оправки, приема и вычислений.
Можно побольше... можно поменьше... Пц.

Comment: Не, много потоков для отправки и много для приема - сообщения потеряют порядок, потом не разгребешь.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне кажется, что вы потеряете все преимущества на синхронизации. То есть. Если у меня один поток принял данные, то сам их обработал или отдал кому-то и обработал и выслал. В вашем же случае, один поток принял, потом методами безопасной синхронизации отдал пакет. Его обработал другой поток. Потом опять какая-либо блокировка и уже потом отправка.